# Constrained optimization of joint Bernoulli density parametrized by a neural network

Tags: distributions, neural-networks, optimization, density-estimation, constrained-regression

I want to learn a joint distribution on $n$ Bernoulli random variables conditioned on a random variable $b\sim D$ and parametrized by a neural network, $f$:

$$p(A = (a_1, \ldots, a_n)|b) = f_{\Lambda}(b).$$

I require that $\langle A \rangle = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n E[a_i] = p_0$ where $p_0$ is some fixed (typically small) number. Each $A$ is evaluated by some loss function $L(A,b)$. I have tried solving the regularized problem

$$\text{minimize} \ E_{b\sim D}[L(A,b; \Lambda) + \eta (\langle A\rangle - p_0)^2]$$

with backprop, but I find it is difficult to tune $\eta$. Is there some way to impose a hard constraint?

Answer (score 0):

You could have the network parameterize just the first $n-1$ bernoulli RVs and set $p_{n} = np_0 - \sum_i^{n-1} p_i$ defining ($p_i = E[a_i]$). If $p_n$ isn't in $[0,1]$ then "back up" one more step, and set $p_{n-1} = p_n = np_0 - \sum_i^{n-2} p_i$. If this still doesn't keep $p_n$ in $[0,1]$, keep "backing up" until it does.

Comment: I am not sure I follow. The idea is use p_n to model the regularizer in the loss I proposed? I don't yet see how that hardens my constraint. And is the sum in p_j=n*p_0 + sum(p_i) taken over all i \neq j?

Comment: @MRicci as a concrete example -- if $n=3$, and you want to enforce $\frac{1}{3}(p_1+p_2+p_3) = 0.7$, then simply fix $p_3 = 2.1-p_1-p_2$, and your constraint is *always* satisfied.

Comment: Yes, I see what you mean, but my loss, L, depends on there being exactly n random variables so that I'm not sure the addition of an auxiliary variable that _technically_ makes the constraint true (on the enlarged set of variables) solves my problem.

Comment: right, so i'm suggesting that you use your network to parameterize $n-1$ variables, then force the constraint to be true with the last one. It's not an additional auxiliary variable, it's just the last variable you need to reach $n$.